# Python keeps pointing me to the name of the function?

Tags: python

I am a python noob, I have little experience so the code you will witness is garbage. Its a number guessing game. I keep getting a syntax error on the last line pointing me to just before the parenthesis and I cant figure out what the hell is it trying to say. Also any interpreter suggestions? I have a license in VS but I find it to be infuriating to use.

```
def func_guessdude(x):
if user_input == x:
    print("you got it")
elif user_input > x:
    print("just a little less")
else:
    print("just a little more")
user_input == 16
print func_guessdude(15)
```

Comment: Which version of python you are using?

Comment: The `print`-function needs parenthesis.

Comment: `user_input == 16` doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parentheses in you last print: `print(func_guessdude(15))`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to re-format this a bit:

```
def func_guessdude(x):
    if user_input == x:
        print("you got it")
    elif user_input > x:
        print("just a little less")
    else:
        print("just a little more")

user_input = 16

func_guessdude(15)
```

This returns "just a little less."

Comment: Because 15 is the "real answer"

Answer (score 0):

```
def func_guessdude(x):
    global user_input
    if user_input == x:
        print("you got it")
    elif user_input > x:
        print("just a little less")
    else:
        print("just a little more")
user_input = 16
print func_guessdude(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your code be like:

```
user_input = 16
def func_guessdude(x):
    if user_input == x:
        return "you got it"
    elif user_input > x:
        return "just a little less"
    else:
        return "just a little more"

print (func_guessdude(15))
```

You initialized user_input after your if else, and also your method is not returning anything

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I finally fixed it up to work fine, thanks to kfazi for clearing the main issue out. I am not completely sure what a global var is yet, have to google it. Thanks for the responses. This code should return "you got it"

```
def func_guessdude(x):
    user_input = 16
    if user_input == x:
        return("you got it")
    elif user_input > x:
        return("just a little less")
    else:
        return("just a little more")
print(func_guessdude(16))
```